Check if an Excel workbook is opened and ready
I have a Python script that opens Excel workbooks in a loop, fills them out and saves them (the xlsx files are rather big). Sometimes, when running I get this error:
com_error: (-2147418111, 'Call was rejected by callee.', None, None)

I checked that it might be because SaveAs command is executed when Open command is not finished yet and it crashes. I am trying to create a check within the script after the Open command to check whether the Excel file is fully open and ready and if not, i want to force 1 second of sleep time.
I tried this:
def Is_file_ready(workbook):
    try:
        _ = workbook.sheets[0]
        return True
    except Exception:
        return False

wb = app.books.open({filepath})

while not Is_file_ready(wb):
      time.sleep(1)

But unfortunately, the script still crashes with the same error.

which package for opening the excel workbook do you use?

I am using xlwings

does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49883687/xlwings-book-hangs-if-file-is-already-open

I saw this thread but it's a different issue and error that occurs

We can try checking readiness of the workbook until it confirms that the workbook is fully opened.
app = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
app.Visible = False
filepath = "path_to_your_excel_file.xlsx"
max_retries = 30  # Adjust this number as needed
wb = app.Workbooks.Open(filepath)
retries = 0
while not is_file_ready(wb):
    time.sleep(1)
    retries += 1
    if retries > max_retries:
        print("Failed to open the workbook after multiple attempts.")
        break
if retries <= max_retries:
    wb.SaveAs(filepath)
wb.Close(SaveChanges=False)
app.Quit()

